# Unable to remove directory app.publish

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I can't change permissions on folder.
If I try to delete folder I get a "access denied".

It does not help to open VS with admin rights.

The only thing that works is signing out.

I am running Win8

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue - have you found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not running any version control program in the background that locks these files. I had this problem and solved it by closing EasyMercurial and re-build.